# About chrome page loading issue

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, browser

I'm a stranger here :)

Actually, I have used Ubuntu as a main OS with my notebook about for a year.

And Chrome has been a my primary web browser. You know, chrome was the best browser for me 2 weeks ago.

Suddenly Chrome's web page loading speed was low and I tried to find that reason many times but failed to do it.

Even though, with more and more googling, I can't take care of it. I removed chrome and re-install it over and over again, that didn't work at all.

Anyway I got to know existence of Chromium that is open source version of Chrome and I installed it. Wow, Chromium works!!!!

Yeah, about a week, Chromium was good for me. But finally, the same situation I mentioned above was brougt about for me.

As a last action to be taken, I use chrome in my virtual machine installed windows 7.
You know, in my guest Os ( win 7) chrome works well. How could it be?

That's all I tried to tell you guys. Anyone can help me?

Comment: How is your general download speed in other browsers or with tools like `wget`?

Comment: @David Foerster I can't tell what you told with accurate numeric value. But the important thing is another browers, like firefox,Opera etc, are showing more slow download speed than chrome is. I don't know why this issue occurs, but I think it depends on own user's computing envrionment.That's all.

Comment: Please run `wget -O /dev/null http://cachefly.cachefly.net/10mb.test` and see if the reported data rate meets your expectation. If it's not underwhelming, we can go on and try to find out what makes your web browsers slow.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I tested it. But I have a question. Does wget affects browsers with its task? For more detail, if wget is downloading test contents, Does it give its performance effect to browsers? I think wget only does its task within OS boundary. What do you think of it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `wget` is an HTTP client like a web browser, but it cannot display web pages (or anything other content for that matter). As such, it provides a simple and robust way do test internet connection speed. I thought that was, what your issue, but reading your question again, your issue might have been with *page rendering speed*, not *download speed*. Please clarify.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Let's make problem simple! Actually, I had a question about chrome rendering issue. Yea,it's true. And I solved a problem with avi software's answer. As avi software told, I turned off chrome's "Use hardware acceleartion when available" , And chrome's rendering issue was solved. But, I think It's weired that another OS(Win 7) - Guest OS in my virtual machine - has chrome's setting with "Use hardware acceleration available" to be "ON" , and chrome rendering issue never occurs unlike my host OS, Ubuntu.

Comment: How could it be? Anyway, I don't understand what's your purpose to ask me of download speed test. So, furthermore wget's functionality doesn't matter of this chrome issue, I think. Are you clear on me? I'll be wating your feedback. and Thank you for your constant attention.

Comment: I misunderstood which speed you had issues with: I thought downloading, you meant page rendering. Sorry about that. Your VM guest system uses a different graphics driver than your host system. Renderers sometimes have regressive performance issues with particular drivers that make them slower with powerful graphics hardware than with a different driver on less powerful (including virtualised) hardware.

Comment: in addtion to what I told, here's my brief point. 1) My host OS' chrome has been set to be "ON" with "Use acceleartion when available" since I istalled chrome. 2) Rendering issue with chrome didnt' occured, but someday it happend to me. 3) I compared difference between my host OS and guest OS. ,Actually guest Os was set to be "ON" with "Use acceleartion when available" like my host OS. 4)But my guest OS' chrome works well. 5) At this point, I wonder how it is possible. That's all.

Comment: Ah,That'ok. Never mind of your misunderstanding :) Anyway, I thought graphic drivers's issue like you also. and I tried to update my graphic drivers but It's difficult for to me do that. So, I keep chrome's setting to be "OFF" with "Use hardware acceleartion when available" option.

Comment: Yes, I would do the same. You should try to enable hardware acceleration again after a while after updates to either your graphics driver or Chrome/Chromium.

Comment: I checked my intel graphic driver's version and found it is lates t version. So chrome is. Haha, I dont' know what is real soulution to this problem :(

Comment: The issue is a combination of the two. Maybe Chrome developers were working around a former issue of the driver that has now been fixed in a way that makes the workaround cause problems.

Comment: Hmm, I wrote "report an issue" about my situation to google. Let's see how's it going :) And I'll keep in touch about outcome of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to disable GPU acceleration on settings board.

**To fix it:**
go to settings.
search for "acceleration" on the search box.
clear the check box on the "Use hardware acceleration when available."
restart it.

It is bug in chromium.
you can see [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=454898).

Comment: Wow,thanx for your help indeed :) as you mentioned above, I did that so and chrome works well !!!!! appreciate it again. Have a nice one :-)

Comment: @James The way to say thankyou here is by upvoting and accepting the answer. See the top arrow on the left top side and the check mark, please click on those.

Answer (score -3):

Try to Update The Packages using these commands in terminal (Alt+ctrl+T) ...

**sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf**

**sudo apt-get update**

Comment: What will doing this accomplish really?