# Glitches while trying to scroll pages in Chromium

Tags: chromium, scrolling

When I try to scroll pages in Chromium Browser, pages don't render properly. There are these stuck block of glitches all over the pages. These glitches disappear when I switch tab and return back to the same tab. But as soon as I start scrolling again, they appear. Sometimes highlighting the contents of the page or hovering the mouse over the glitches also does the trick.

Here is the version I am using - Version 42.0.2298.0 Ubuntu 14.10 (64-bit)

Is this an issue with Chromium itself, Ubuntu, or the plugins I have been installing in Chromium?

Comment: Look if it is similar to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/583806/about-chrome-page-loading-issue)

Comment: @avi software Nope that wasn't the issue. I have my hardware acceleration disabled.

Comment: Are you still having this problem? Presumably you are no longer using 14.10, so did you manage to fix it or did it go away after an upgrade?