# How to fix Chrome/Chromium glitch in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: google-chrome, intel-graphics, chromium

I am experiencing glithces in Chrome and Chromium browsers under Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit), as shown in the picture.

[image: Chromium Glitch]

My browser versions are

- Chromium 53.0.2785.143 Built on Ubuntu
- Chrome   54.0.2840.100 (64-bit)
- Firefox  49.02

Firefox does not present this issue.

I have a

```
 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
```

on a Thinkpad X250.

Solutions provided in [Annoying flickering in 16.04 LTS - Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766725/annoying-flickering-in-16-04-lts-chrome) (disable GPU acceleration) do not work.

The kind of glithces are **not** like this 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l21WsKz3fZc&feature=youtu.be&t=45s

or this
[Glitches while trying to scroll pages in Chromium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587195/glitches-while-trying-to-scroll-pages-in-chromium)

Launchpad bug report page is
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1643208