# Very slow Chromium browser

Tags: 14.10, google-chrome, performance, chromium, debugging

On my machine Chromium is very slow, I had to switch to Firefox where everything works fine.
Looks like this is a kind of JavaScript problem (eg. slowed down typing on Facebook), pages loading slower, feels like the pages are heavy.

Is there any option to fix this? How to debug the problem?

Clean install
Chromium 41.0.2272.76 Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: In Chromium's tab strip area, right click and select Task Manager. Is there any process taking a significant chunk of the CPU?

Comment: @saiarcot895 GPU process takes up to 80% when I type in the facebook textarea.

Comment: see if it is similar to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/583806/about-chrome-page-loading-issue) , and try to disable GPU acceleration

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/712504/chrome-running-slow/988156#988156

Comment: This is maybe some problem with hardware acceleration in ubuntu?

Answer (score 9):

As suggested by @Avi disabling the GPU solved this issue in my case.

I proceeded as suggested in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1315598) and disabled the use of gpu for my chrome. For such, you just need to start it with the `--disable-gpu` flag.

You can also do as shown [in this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/583806/about-chrome-page-loading-issue), by changing the settings. For this go at `chrome://settings/` > `Advanced` and uncheck `Use hardware acceleration`.

*As you can see, this seems to be an issue and both ways are just workarounds. Let's hope future versions fix this issue and this question/solution becomes obsolete.*

Comment: Makes no difference.

Comment: 2017 and the same bug in FreeBSD...drat. This answer is GOLD.

Comment: 2020 and this solution still works! Even on Windows!

Comment: 2021 and hoooray it works! Thanks a lot.

Comment: 2022 this worked, what is weird is one day it was fine and the next it was slow

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 14.10. The problem was solved when I upgraded Ubuntu to 15.04. BTW "Adobe Brackets" is also gets normal from "very slow".